# Repeat.for binding hangs with latest chrome version

Tags: google-chrome, aurelia

I'm facing a problem in a view containing a `repeat.for` binding. When chrome was updated to the latest version my app started to hang.

Any suggestions on how to find the problem?

Here is a code sample (it's quite hard to put it all here) :

```html
<section class="split split2  splitTo2 flexCol">
  <div class="titleBar">
    <div class="breadCrumbs floatLeft">
      <h3 class="cursorDefault">Configuration</h3> <span class="cursorDefault">/</span>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="pageBody">
    <dynamic-table list.bind="list | filter:selectedTableType:filterByTypeFunc" text-filter.bind="tableTextFilter.value" containerless>
    </dynamic-table>
  </div>
</section>
```

The `<dynamic-table>` custom element has a table with repeat for binding, as follows:

```html
<table class="grid table table-striped table-bordered" if.bind="list.length>0 && canDraw" show.bind="canDraw">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th repeat.for="col of cols">
        <a click.trigger="gridSort(col.colName)"> ${col.label} <img if.bind="col.headerImg" src.bind="col.headerImg" style="width: 18px;height: 18px"/> <i class="sortIcon fa ${col.colName | gridSortIcon:gridSortObject & signal:'gridSortColChanged'}"></i></a>
      </th>
      <th if.bind="canEdit"></th>
      <th if.bind="canDelete"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody ref="tableBody">
    <tr repeat.for="row of list | filter:textFilter:filterFunc | sort:gridSortObject.colName:gridSortObject.desc | pagination:pageSize:currentPage">

      <td repeat.for="col of cols" name="${col.colName}" innerhtml.bind="row[col.colName] | convertManager:col.converters"></td>

      <td if.bind="canEdit"><span class="gridButton gridEdit fa fa-pencil" click.delegate="_editGridIRow(row)" authorize="${authorizePrifex +'_edit'}"></span></th>
        <td if.bind="canDelete"><span class="gridButton gridDelete fa fa-times" click.delegate="_deleteGridIRow(row)" authorize="${authorizePrifex +'_delete'}"></span></th>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

`cols` is a collection containing the table column names, and `list` has 15 rows. I verified that it performs 15 iterations, repeating 5 times (which seems very weird).

Any direction on how can I debug that repeat binding?

Comment: Are you able to duplicate the issue in a sample at http://gist.run?

Comment: I posted it above , quite hard to add it to gist.run with a working state.

Comment: it could have no effect at all, but you're closing some `td` elements with a `th` tag.

Comment: Believe or not !! the problem was with an li style of 'inline-block' !!!!!

Answer (score 1):

I got the exact same kind of error today: latest version of chrome lead to a freeze of my application, while other browsers were working fine.

I fixed the issue the same way as you by changing a CSS line (mine was the **height value of a div**). Although the issue was on my side, I am not sure that hanging the webapp because of a css line of code is the expected behavior.

Comment: I think the Airelia team should check it , since there are two cases of this crazy bug.